# Adding characters from an external file to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, updating

In python, how would i select a single character from a txt document that contains the following:

A#

M*

N%

(on seperate lines)...and then update a dictionary with the letter as the key and the symbol as the value.

The closest i have got is:

```
ftwo = open ("clues.txt", "r")
for lines in ftwo.readlines():
    for char in lines:
```

I'm pretty new to coding so cant work it out!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that each line contains extactly two characters (first the key, then the value):

```
with open('clues.txt', 'r') as f:
    myDict = {a[0]: a[1] for a in f}
```

If you have empty lines in your input file, you can filter these out:

```
with open('clues.txt', 'r') as f:
    myDict = {a[0]: a[1] for a in f if a.strip()}
```

Comment: I think that you need to create the empty dictionary and then add the individual key elements. I think that your code resets the dictionary to each individual row so that you are left with only the final input of a as the single entry in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to read each line one at a time:

```
my_dict = {}
with open ("clues.txt", "r") as ftwo:
    for line in ftwo:
        # Then, you'll want to put your elements in a dict
        my_dict[line[0]] = line[1]
```